# Hibernate Validator: Built-in Way to Use Locale for Validation Messages

Tags: bean-validation, hibernate-validator

Is there any built-in mechanism or simple integration with Hibernate Validator so that I can use the HttpRequestServlet's locale to generate validation messages?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no out-of-the-box solution for this currently.

You'd have to plug in a custom message interpolator which applies the right locale. Unfortunately, the solution likely will be a bit hack-ish at this point. E.g. check out this post on a description for [solving the issue](https://jaxenter.com/integrating-bean-validation-with-jax-rs-2-106887.html) for JAX-RS.

Comment: Thanks for the response @gunnar. I'll take a look.